Need script to check all Windows users for if and which version of Microsoft Teams Classic is installed
I'm looking for a script to check all Windows users for if, and which, version of Microsoft Teams Classic is installed. This script needs to be ran from power shell. I put something together awhile back, but recently realized just how bad it is. Not only does it not check all users (current only) it includes a ton of extra info you need to look through to find an answer that is sometimes partially correct at best.
What do y'all use for looking for Teams?
(In the meantime I'll be working on building a new, good script)
I've tried a bunch of uninstall scripts but none return what is installed after the script runs. Validating results is problematic

Previous script is as follows:
$cu=((Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username).split("\")[1];(cat \Users\$cu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\logs.txt).split(",") | Select-String "version 1.6"
Depending on the version I might have deleted the 6 found in version to search for any semi recent versions.

I've made the following and so far it does everything I want. It identifies all users on a device, if Teams Classic is installed, prints which version is installed and if it is not installed on that user it states that user does not have Teams installed. Let me know if y'all have something else you're using.
#Enumerate local users

$Users | ForEach-Object {

#Locate Teams Installation folder
    $localAppData = "$($ENV:SystemDrive)\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\curent\Teams.exe"

    If (Test-Path "$($localAppData)")
        {
            Write-Warning "$($_.Name) has $((get-itemproperty -Path $localAppData).VersionInfo.FileVersion) installed."
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output "Teams installation not found for user $($_.Name)"
        }
}

